# swig: suppress warning about function being python keyword

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a C++ library and I use swig to generate Python bindings for it. Many classes have a print function, for them I get a warning like this:

```
Foo.h:81: Warning 314: 'print' is a python keyword, renaming to '_print'
```

How can I suppress the warnings? I tried

```
%ignore print;
```

But it did not help. Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expected that using  the [warning filtering](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Warnings.html) syntax:

```
%warnfilter(314) print;
```

would do the trick, however in this instance it didn't seem to work. I was however able to fix the warning by explicitly doing the rename myself using `%rename`:

```
%module test
%rename(_print) print;
void print();
```

`%ignore` does also work with SWIG 3.0. Best guess you had the directive and the declaration in the wrong order for example:

```
%module test
%ignore print;
void print();
```

Does not warn with 3.0.2

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much.